# How to import SSIS package from server to SSIS project in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, wizard

I have SSIS project, now I want to add an exist package in server into this project. I looked for tutorial in youtube, google,.... but found no answer.

I right click on SSIS Package, and select SSIS Import and Export Wizard
[image]

In Data Link Properties window, test connection always return success when I change anything, but when click next step, error come
[image]

[image]

I dont know how to pass this step :(

Answer (score 0):

The SSIS Import and Export Wizard is not the tool to add existing packages to your project. The SSIS Import and Export Wizard is a GUI for building SSIS packages, usually in a disposable fashion.

I don't know how to fire up the Integration Services Import Project Wizard for an existing project, but if you add a new project, you can pick the Import Project Wizard which will then pull in the existing packages (and project level connection managers and project parameters)

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I can add existing ssis package from sql server into SSIS project in visual studio as new project, but maybe unable to import it into visual studio existing project. :(

Comment: An option: Add new project to the existing solution and import the target project. Then in the existing project, Add each package from the new project. Then add any Project level Connection Managers or Parameter entries. Then delete the newly created project.